# Codigo de php para guardado en base de datos no ejecuta en servidor web

Tags: php, javascript, html, hosting, cpanel

Esto sera un poco extenso y cabe aclarar que esto me funciona en localhost y un servidor gratuito llamado zz.com.ve
Tengo los siguientes archivos en la siguiente carpeta
directorio/clases/categorias.php

```
<?php
 class categorias{
     public function agregaCategoria($datos){
         $c= new conectar();
         $conexion=$c->conexion();
         $sql="INSERT into categorias(id_usuario, nombreCategoria, cargo, extension, directo, fechaCaptura) values ('$datos[0]','$datos[1]','$datos[2]','$datos[3]','$datos[4]','$datos[5]')";
         return mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
     }

     public function eliminaCategoria($idcategoria){
        $c= new conectar();
         $conexion=$c->conexion();
         $sql="DELETE from categorias where id_categoria='$idcategoria'";
        return mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
     }

       }
?>
```

directorio/procesos/categorias/agregaCategoria

```
<?php
 session_start();
require_once "../../clases/conexionbd.php";
require_once "../../clases/categorias.php";

$fecha=date("Y-m-d");
$idusuario=$_SESSION['iduser'];
$nombreCategoria=$_POST['nombreCategoria'];
$cargo=$_POST['cargo'];
$extension=$_POST['extension'];
$directo=$_POST['directo'];
$datos=array(
    $idusuario, $nombreCategoria, $cargo, $extension, $directo, $fecha

);
$obj= new categorias();
echo $obj->agregaCategoria($datos);
?>
```

directorio/procesos/categorias/eliminarCategoria

```
<?php
require_once "../../clases/conexionbd.php";
require_once "../../clases/categorias.php";
    $id=$_POST['idcategoria'];
    $obj=new categorias();
    echo $obj->eliminaCategoria($id);
?>
```

directorio/vistas/categorias/tablaCategorias

```
<?php
require_once "../../clases/conexionbd.php";
 session_start();
    $c= new conectar();
            $conexion=$c->conexion();

            $sql="SELECT id_categoria,nombreCategoria,cargo,extension,directo 
                    FROM categorias";
            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

     ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" style="text-align: center;">
<thead class="bg-info"> 
    <tr>
        <td >Trabajador</td>
        <td>Cargo</td>
        <td>Extensión</td>
        <td>Directo</td>
        <?php
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="admin"):
         ?>
         <td>Editar</td>
        <td>Eliminar</td>
        <?php 
       endif;
          ?>
          <?php
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="comercializacion"):
         ?>
         <td>Editar</td>
        <td>Eliminar</td>
        <?php 
       endif;
          ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        require '../../conexion.php';
    $consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM categorias");
    while ($ver=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
        $id_categoria=$ver['id_categoria'];
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$ver['2'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ver['3'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ver['4'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ver['5'].'</td>';
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="admin"):
        echo '<td><a href="editar_categoria.php?id_categoria='.$id_categoria.'"><span class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            </span></a></td>';
        echo '<td>
            <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="eliminaCategoria('.$ver[0].')">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </span>

        </td>'; 
         endif;
         if($_SESSION['usuario']=="comercializacion"):
        echo '<td><a href="editar_categoria.php?id_categoria='.$id_categoria.'"><span class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            </span></a></td>';
        echo '<td>
            <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="eliminaCategoria('.$ver[0].')">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </span>

        </td>'; 
         endif;
        echo '</tr>';
    }

          ?>
</table>
</div>
```

categorias.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="gb18030">
    <title>  </title>
    <?php 
    require_once "menu.php";
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
      <h1 class="panel-title">
        <a style="color: white" class="btn btn-success" href="directorio.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Volver &nbsp;

            </a>
      Agrega Aqui El trabajador </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <form id="frmCategorias" method="post">
            <label>Trabajador</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="50" name="nombreCategoria" id="nombreCategoria">
            <label>Cargo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="50" name="cargo" id="cargo">
            <?php
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="admin"):
         ?>
            <label>Extensión</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="3" name="extension" id="extension">
            <label>Directo</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control input-sm" minlength="7" maxlength="7" name="directo" id="directo" placeholder="Ej: 2779533">
            <p></p>
                 <?php 
       endif;
          ?>
          <br>
          <?php
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="admin"):
         ?>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAgregaCategoria" value="Agregar">
             <?php 
       endif;
          ?>
          <?php
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="comercializacion"):
         ?>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAgregaCategoria" value="Agregar">
             <?php 
       endif;
          ?>
            </form>
        </div>
<!--EN col sm 6 se puede modificar con un numero mayor en caso de que no se vea completo el nombre de la categoria-->
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div id="tablacategoriacargar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#tablacategoriacargar').load("../directorio/vistas/categorias/tablaCategorias.php");

            $('#btnAgregaCategoria').click(function(){

                vacios=validarFormVacio('frmCategorias');

                if(vacios > 0){
                    alertify.alert('Ops... Algo Salio Mal!','Debes llenar todos los campos!!');
                    return false;
                }

                datos=$('#frmCategorias').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:datos,
                    url:"../directorio/procesos/categorias/agregaCategoria.php",
                    success:function(r){
                        if(r==1){
                    //esta linea nos permite limpiar el formulario al insertar un registro
                     $('#frmCategorias')[0].reset();
          $('#tablacategoriacargar').load("../directorio/vistas/categorias/tablaCategorias.php");
          alertify.success("Categoria agregada con exito :D");
                }else{
alertify.error("No se pudo agregar categoria");
                }
            }
        });
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
    }
    else{
        header("Location:../index.php");
    }

?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function eliminaCategoria(idcategoria){
alertify.confirm('Deseas eliminar esta informacion?', function(){ 
 $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      data:"idcategoria=" + idcategoria,
      url:"../directorio/procesos/categorias/eliminarCategoria.php",
      success:function(r){
          if(r==1){
            $('#tablacategoriacargar').load("../directorio/vistas/categorias/tablaCategorias.php");
              alertify.success("Eliminado");
          }else{
            alertify.error("No se elimino");
          }
      }
    });
}, function(){ 
  alertify.error('Cancelado')
});

}
</script>
```

editar_categoria.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
$id_categoria=$_GET['id_categoria'];
require 'conexion.php';
$buscar=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE id_categoria='$id_categoria'");
$fila=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar);
$nombreCategoria=$fila['nombreCategoria'];
$cargo=$fila['cargo'];
$extension=$fila['extension'];
$directo=$fila['directo'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php 
    require_once "menu.php";
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
<div  class="panel-heading"><a style="color: white" class="btn btn-success" href="redireccion.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Volver &nbsp;

            </a> Editar</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
<form action="modificar_categoria.php" method="POST">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>

    <th>Nombre Trabajador
    <input type="hidden" name="id_categoria" value="<?php echo $id_categoria;?>">
    <input type="text" name="nombreCategoria" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $nombreCategoria;?>"></th>
    <th>Cargo
    <input type="text" name="cargo" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $cargo;?>"></th>

  <input type="hidden" name="extension" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $extension;?>"></th>
  <input type="hidden" name="directo"  maxlength="7" value="<?php echo $directo;?>"></th>
    <?php
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="admin"):
         ?>
    <th>Extensión
    <input type="text" name="extension" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $extension;?>"></th>
    <th>Directo
    <input type="text" name="directo" maxlength="7" value="<?php echo $directo;?>"></th>
    <!-- Codigo para la visualizacion del admin o usuario encargado !-->
    <?php 
       endif;
          ?>
    <?php
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="admin"):
         ?>
    <th><input type="submit" value="Guardar"></th>
    <?php 
       endif;
          ?>
          <?php
        if($_SESSION['usuario']=="comercializacion"):
         ?>
    <th><input type="submit" value="Guardar"></th>
    <?php 
       endif;
          ?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else{
        header("Location:../index.php");
    }

?>
```

modificar_categoria.php

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
error_reporting(0);
$id_categoria=$_POST['id_categoria'];
$nombreCategoria=$_POST['nombreCategoria'];
$cargo=$_POST['cargo'];
$extension=$_POST['extension'];
$directo=$_POST['directo'];
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE categorias SET nombreCategoria='$nombreCategoria', cargo='$cargo', extension='$extension', directo='$directo' WHERE id_categoria='$id_categoria'");

?>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript>
   window.history.go(-2)
</SCRIPT>
```

Una ves visto todo el codigo les indico lo siguiente
1)Si intento agregar una categoria esto no me lo guarda pero si refresca la tabla (su funcion comun al momento de registrar)
2)Si agrego datos directamente de la base de datos esto me lo muestra en la tabla
3)Puedo editar sin problemas los datos y guardarlos
4)Puedo eliminar sin problemas
5)Tengo una tabla llamado usuarios es literalmente el mismo codigo y este si hace sus funciones
ATTE: Les recuerdo que en mi localhost y en un servidor web gratuito llamado zz.com.ve si me los acepta sin ningun problema

Comment: Si imprimes esta variable en la función de guardar **$datos**, tienes los datos en el mismo orden que haces el insert?

Comment: en la bd? si...

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de columna es `fechaCaptura` y cómo estás enviando la fecha?

Comment: $fecha=date("Y-m-d"); automatico